# DATE_FORMAT(inventory_dateTime,'%Y-%m-%d')

Tags: php, html, mysql, datepicker

I am doing a project using jquery template and it has a datepicker and format gives as `11/01/2015 (month/date/year)`, but while I am adding that to the database it doesn't give any output cause of violation of pattern. Could anyone please tell me how to change it into
`2015-11-01 (year-month- date)`

I used this but it didn't work

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(inventory_dateTime,'%d-%m-%Y')
FROM `db_thisurienterprice`.`tbl_inventory`
where inventory_dateTime between '11/30/2014'  and '11/30/2015'
```

Comment: what's the datatype of inventory_dateTime?

Comment: inserting to data base use `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($YOUR_DATE))`

Comment: You can change the way jQuery [stores the date](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) and [displays the date](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat). And these can be two different values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to convert your string `'11/30/2014'` & `'11/30/2015'` into date which you can simply convert it using `str_to_date` function, so kindly update your query into

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(inventory_dateTime,'%d-%m-%Y') FROM 
db_thisurienterprice.tbl_inventory where inventory_dateTime between 
str_to_date('11/30/2014', '%m/%d/%Y') and str_to_date('11/30/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`inventory_dateTime`,'%d-%m-%Y') FROM `db_thisurienterprice`.`tbl_inventory` where inventory_dateTime between '2015/10/09' and '2015/10/17'
```